# Combine data from two different text files in just one line (Python)

Tags: python, join, text-files, lines

I have two comma delimited text files with content as below:

File1:

> TR,23456.23,H,56789
>
> TR,54678.13,F,14567
>
> TR,67889.12,R,89876

File2:

> SG,6789.24,J,53452
>
> SG,8909.25,F,56789
>
> SG,5467.11,S,56783

I want to extract sentences from the first and second file and combine them in a new text file in just one line as below:

> TR,54678.13,F,14567,SG,8909.25,F,56789

However, in my code, the result obtained is the following:

> TR,54678.13,F,14567
>
> ,SG,8909.25,F,56789

Why the sentences from the second file are being written below the sentences from the first file?. I need both sentences to be combined on the same line. Does anybody know why is this happening and how could I solve the problem?.

This is my code:

```
contfil=0
direct=os.listdir(path1)
for file in direct:
  with open(os.path.join(save_path1,file),'r') as Textfile1:
    for eachline1 in Textfile1:
       for field in eachline1.split():
           ID1=field.split(',') [2]
           with open(os.path.join(save_path2,os.listdir(save_path2) [contfil]),'r') as Textfile2:
               for eachline2 in Textfile2:
                   for field in eachline2.split():
                        ID2=field.split(',') [2]
                        if ID2==ID1:
                           fo=open(os.path.join(save_path3,'Matched_Lines.txt'),'a')
                           fo.write('%s,%s\n' %(eachline1,eachline2))
                           fo.close()
  contfil+=1
```

Comment: Try printing `repr(eachline1)` and `repr(eachline2)`. See anything on the end?

Comment: python has csv module for reading these types of files

Comment: What does ' '.join(eachline1, eachline2) produce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is `strip` each line. Change this line:

```
fo.write('%s,%s\n' %(eachline1,eachline2))
```

to this:

```
fo.write('%s,%s\n' %(eachline1.strip(),eachline2.strip()))
```

What's happening is that each line you read in has a newline (`\n`) at the end. When you print them out, that newline is output. `strip` removes the newline before outputting.

Comment: `trim` isn't a python builtin. I think you're thinking of JavaScript's `String.trim()`? A python equivalent would be `str.strip` or `str.rstrip`.

Comment: Yeah, I realized the mistake almost immediately. It's fixed. I've been using too many languages recently....

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try

```
combinedline = ' '.join([eachline1, eachline2])
```

and then

```
 fo.write('%s\n', % combinedline)
```

Comment: I have also tried this way but I get the following error: "join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)". It might not work for my case?. I have copied the code as you wrote it above.

Comment: @Sarah thanks for pointing out my typo. join will take each entry in a list and join them with the preceding string. I forgot the square brackets. Sorry about that.

Comment: Not a problem. There is another mistake in the code, the comma before the %. I have tried it again, now it works but I obtain the same results as with my initial code (One line below the other one and not their combination).